# DjangoAdmin: Add Enable/Disable Link for Certain Model in List Page

Tags: list, django-admin, action

I want to add a link (or html form with submit button) to run some logic upon certain model.

I have a User model with boolean field 'disabled'.

I want to add a link (or html form with submit button) to every table rows which if user clicks on it, the user which related on that row (for example user with id 100) make disabled (and vice versa scenario for enable it).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you considered simply making this field editable in the list view, using the [`ModelAdmin.list_editable`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable) attribute?

Comment: I think I didn't good explained my question! Actually I don't want make read_only/editable field(s) in listview or changeview! I want add custom button which if user clicks on it, do something upon model! for example add 'disable' button to set 'disabled' field of model to True or vice versa.